# Android - textfile- webserver

Tags: android, web, server

i'm doing an android app, and i want to read a text file from a server (http://10.0.2.2:8080/myserver/arquivo.txt) and shows this text in my app.
I don't know how to do this.
can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get the response:

```
String textFileUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/myserver/arquivo.txt"
String textFileText;


    Request httpRequest = new Request();
            httpRequest.execute(textFileUrl);
            try {
                textFileText = httpRequest.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
System.out.println("The online text file contains: " + textFileText);

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setText(textFileText);
```

Create a new file named Request.java:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class Request extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    HttpResponse response = null;

    public Request(){


    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();

            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem on  : @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        TextView text=(TextView)findviewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(response);



    }

Comment: @ClaudioCastro Check the answer, I've added a new line at the bottom of the first piece of code that puts the received text into the textview. Make sure you have the INTERNET permission declared in your Android Manifest!

Comment: thanks! now, in my case, the 'text' that i got  is a number. How can i use this like a variable?

Comment: @ClaudioCastro is it a number with decimals?? If no use int textFileNumber = Integer.parseInt(textFileText); If yes; use float textFileNumber = Float.parseFloat(textFileText); a double may also work: double textFileNumer = Double.parseDouble(textFileText);

Comment: thanks for your help! everything is working well! but i have one more question: do you know how can i update the value clicking on a button??

Comment: Use in your onClickListener use httpRequest.execute(textFileUrl); and then do textView.setText(textFileUrl); BUT make sure that the textView is publically visible by declaring it below the class name!